# DSPL Missing value using Python script

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file and want to add a xml file to it, so I use the DSPL Generator:
https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/dsplgen?hl=de-DE

But my problem is, that I have a missing value in my csv file and the script cannot read it correctly. If I change the "MISSING VALUE" to e.g. zero, then everything is ok, but for further analysis this is not good, because the value is not zero but missing!

A sample from my CSV file:

```
Platz[type=integer],Land[type=string],Gold[type=integer],Silber[type=integer],Bronze[type=integer],Gesamt[type=integer],GNI[type=float],Lifeexpectancy[type=float],Meanyearsofschooling[type=float],Mortalityunderfive[type=float],PopulationTotal[type=float],Totalexpenditureonhealth[type=float],CommunistSocialist[type=float],Populationbelow[type=float],CountrySize[type=float],Militaryexpenditure[type=float],Totalexpenditureoneducation[type=float],year[type=date]
1,United States,46,29,29,104,43017.00044,78.531,12.4452,8,313.08538,16.20982063,0,0,9629091,4.713270174,5.45094,2011
2,China,38,27,23,88,7476.355864,73.456,7.549,19,1347.565324,4.566156614,1,15.92,9596960,1.951861141,MISSING VALUE,2011
```

the value MISSING VALUE in the second row (china) is my problem

Comment: I think that the DSPL generator expects a comma separator between columns, while your csv is using a semicolon.
Also, what is the meaning of the `..` value in the third line?

Comment: ok youre right, the csv is more below, you got the wrong csv! In the correct csv, the ; are already , and the , are . I corrected it above.


So the .. is also a missing value, that's my problem! @Lior could you help? That would be great!

Comment: Have you tried just omitting the value? For example, `1.951861141,,2011` ?

Comment: @Lior Yes, I have tried this, but it does not work, I get an error message:

Evaluating column year
Guessing that column year is a dimension
Guessing that column year is formatted as yyyy a
Reading CSV data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\dsplgen.py", line 12
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\dsplgen.py", line 99
    csv_file, options['verbose'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dspllib\da
line 323, in __init__
    typed_row_value = float(row_value)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: